# React native bundling of js failed while running on android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

In packager I am getting the following error when I am running the command

**react-native run-android**

The packager output is:

```
 Loading dependency graph...
        Bundling `index.js`  [development, non-minified]  ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░  0.0% (0/1)Error: watch 
 ENOSPC
    at _errnoException (util.js:1019:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1383:19)
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1409:11)
    at NodeWatcher.watchdir
```

Any help? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the steps:

- Kill my node server process which is started on 8081 port.
- Restarted my complete development environment
- And then started my packager(`react-native start`) **as super user**.
- then executed `react-native run-android`.

And it is running successfully now.

Answer (score 6):

Try to re run the project and clean the project, `cd android` and then `gradlew clean`, and I suggest to run `react-native start` first, then open a new terminal and run `react-native run-android`, also i found the troubleshooting case which is quite similar, https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/troubleshooting.html#unable-to-start-react-native-package-manager-on-linux hope that helps:)

Comment: i edited my answer, i added the troubleshooting page which is quite similar to your question